# Showing ppt error

Tags: html, powerpoint

Hi I have a problem I have the code for this button, that is suposed to show a .pptx it the code works in chrome but it doesn't in IE8, it makes me try to download a zip... help please!

```
<button onclick="location.href=('EDTUserManual.pptx');" onmouseover="document.body.style.cursor='hand';" onmouseout="document.body.style.cursor='default';" style="background:url(images/midpattern.gif); background:repeat; border:#036"><font color="#FFFFFF" size="1"><strong>User Manual</strong></font></button>
```

Comment: Well I have fixed it by changing pptx to ppt thanks anyway!

Comment: There are probably other ways around the problem.  
Check the last paragraph on this page:  http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00911_Office_files_don-t_download_correctly_from_a_Web_Server-_saved_as_zip_files_instead.htm  (in later MSIE versions, the option may be called "MIME sniffing" instead of what's shown on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a value to your button. Like this:

```
    value="submit"
```